# WPF Touchscreen User Interface Guidelines

Tags: wpf, user-interface

Does anyone know of any good resources relating to UI design, specifically focusing on WPF and touchscreens?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 16):

After a bit of navigating through MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872774.aspx

Check out the tree on the left for design guidelines on pretty much everything else.  WPF is also mentioned under the "Design Principles" group.

Comment: @Suiva: the link above is the most complete guide available on www.As a recommednation, widen your search by excluding WPF. Search for Touch Screen UI Design. The principles of touch screen design are more important than the technology used.

Comment: The original link is now redirected here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742468.aspx